# Swift 3: Cannot assign to AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, swift3

I try to port the following objective-c code

```
[transferUtility
 enumerateToAssignBlocksForUploadTask:^(AWSS3TransferUtilityUploadTask *uploadTask, __autoreleasing AWSS3TransferUtilityUploadProgressBlock *uploadProgressBlockReference, __autoreleasing AWSS3TransferUtilityUploadCompletionHandlerBlock *completionHandlerReference) {
     NSLog(@"%lu", (unsigned long)uploadTask.taskIdentifier);

     // Use `uploadTask.taskIdentifier` to determine what blocks to assign.

     *uploadProgressBlockReference = // Reassign your progress feedback block.
     *completionHandlerReference = // Reassign your completion handler.
 }
 downloadTask:^(AWSS3TransferUtilityDownloadTask *downloadTask, __autoreleasing AWSS3TransferUtilityDownloadProgressBlock *downloadProgressBlockReference, __autoreleasing AWSS3TransferUtilityDownloadCompletionHandlerBlock *completionHandlerReference) {
     NSLog(@"%lu", (unsigned long)downloadTask.taskIdentifier);

     // Use `downloadTask.taskIdentifier` to determine what blocks to assign.

     *downloadProgressBlockReference =  // Reassign your progress feedback block.
     *completionHandlerReference = // Reassign your completion handler.
 }];
```

to Swift 3

```
        transferUtility.enumerateToAssignBlocks(forUploadTask: { (uploadTask:AWSS3TransferUtilityUploadTask, progress:AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<(@convention(block) (AWSS3TransferUtilityTask, Progress) -> Void)?>?, error: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<(@convention(block) (AWSS3TransferUtilityUploadTask, Error?) -> Void)?>?) in

                        let progressPointer = AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<AWSS3TransferUtilityProgressBlock?>(&self.progressBlock)
                        let completionPointer = AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<AWSS3TransferUtilityUploadCompletionHandlerBlock?>(&self.completionHandler)

                        progress = progressPointer



    }, downloadTask: nil)
```

What I get is that progress is a let constant and I cannot assign to it.

How to fix it?

Comment: Generally, `*someMutablePointer = someValue;` in Objective-C becomes `someMutablePointer.pointee = someValue` in Swift. You need to replace the content pointed by the pointer, no need to create your own pointer.

Comment: Not sure how to do that, could you provide full answer based on example in my question?

Comment: Sorry, I don't use AWS something so I cannot check my code. I do not put unchecked code as an answer as my policy. And you'd better show _what you have done till now_ in your question. You can try even if you are not 100% sure. Or else, you may need a little more time to wait for someone who can help you with AWS- something.

Comment: @OOPer Would you try on my code in github repo? It's test project so I don't have any sensitive data there and it's not complicated, it's just to figure out aws stuff

Comment: You request somebody to try something big without trying something small by yourself????? Try to write some code using `pointee` before asking something. And I have found that you already have similar (the same?) question. You should not post multiple questions on the same issue. Delete this post and continue the old thread.

Comment: 1. I'm not asking you to try something big, I just offered you all-set project with aws to try it if you are not sure if it would work. 2. I tried, it does not work, that's why I asked for a full answer If you will. 3. Yes I have a similar question but this one is specific to pointer stuff, it is just based on the same example. 4. last but not least - nobody is eager to help me out, I browsed the entire internet, tried on reddit, slack, aws help forum and github issues. Nothing. That's why I look a bit frantic. I spent over 20h myself, I really did try sth small, as you said

Comment: OK, I would accept #1 as explanation. For #2, your post has nothing about what you have tried other than the only one. For #3, it depends on your actual intension, to call the AWS API successfully, or just solving the pointer issue? If your intension is the latter, donkon has just solved it. #4, if you feel people are not eager to solve your issue, it may be because your issue is too hard to solve, or maybe because your question is not so appealing. To make your question more appealing, having a respect to the established manner, supplying as much info as you can, all such things would help.

Comment: @OOPer I hope you didn't find my comment aggresive or offensive, I just wanted to be precise about my intention. Thanks for your time, I hope that Donkon answer would work for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign the pointer as seen in the following code:

```
AWSS3TransferUtility.default().enumerateToAssignBlocks(forUploadTask: { (uploadTask:AWSS3TransferUtilityUploadTask, uploadProgressBlockReference:AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<(@convention(block) (AWSS3TransferUtilityTask, Progress) -> Void)?>?, completionHandlerReference: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<(@convention(block) (AWSS3TransferUtilityUploadTask, Error?) -> Void)?>?) in
    print("Hello, world")

    uploadProgressBlockReference?.pointee = {(task:AWSS3TransferUtilityTask, progress:Progress) -> Void in
        print("Fraction completed:  \(progress.fractionCompleted)")
    }
}, downloadTask: nil)
```

Comment: Hi donkon, can I assign my `AWSS3TransferUtilityProgressBlock` object to pointee?
For eg: 
 `uploadProgressBlockReference?.pointee = uploadProgressBlock // uploadProgressBlock is an object of type AWSS3TransferUtilityProgressBlock?`